# VBA Mass email issue

Tags: vba, excel

I am a VBA newbie. I am trying to do a personally tailored mass email to individuals.

This is what I have but I keep getting "object required" error with [the mail_body_message = Sheet1.Range("U3")] highlighted. Then sometimes I get a "not defined" error[Sub SendMassEmail()] highlighted. I need help.  I know I'm close, but it is frustrating.

```
    Sub SendEmail(what_address As String, carbon_copy As String, subject_line As String, mail_body As String)

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    olMail.To = what_address
    olMail.CC = carbon_copy
    olMail.Subject = subject_line
    olMail.Body = mail_body
    olMail.Send


End Sub
Sub SendMassEmail()

row_number = 1

Do
DoEvents
    row_number = row_number + 1
    Dim mail_body_message As String
    Dim full_name As String
    Dim email_address As String
    Dim supervisor_email As String
    Dim date_time As String
    Dim computer_used As String
    Dim device_description As String

    mail_body_message = Sheet1.Range("U3")
    full_name = Sheet1.Range("E" & row_number)
    email_address = Sheet1.Range("F" & row_number)
    supervisor_email = Sheet1.Range("H" & row_number)
    date_time = Sheet1.Range("B" & row_number)
    computer_used = Sheet1.Range("C" & row_number)
    device_description = Sheet1.Range("J" & row_number)
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_name_here", full_name)
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_email_here", email_address)
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_supemail_here", supervisor_email)
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_date_here", date_time)
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_compter_here", computer_used)
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_device_here", device_description)
        MsgBox mail_body_message
        'Call SendEmail(Sheet1.Range("F" & row_number), Sheet1.Range("H" & row_number), "this is a test subject", mail_body_message)

        Last_Row_IN_Column_F = Sheet1.Range("F1000").End(xlUp).Row

Loop Until row_number = Last_Row_IN_Column_F

MsgBox Last_Row_IN_Column_F



End Sub
```

Comment: Is the code name of the sheet `Sheet1`?

Comment: sheet1 is the name of the sheet.

Comment: Do you know the difference between a worksheet name and a worksheet codename?

Comment: Try `mail_body_message = worksheets("Sheet1").Range("U3")`

Comment: obviously not then! lol

Comment: I tried "mail_body_message = worksheets("Sheet1").Range("U3")" and when running i get white blank boxes popping up that seems endless after click "ok" on them.

Answer (score 2):

Tidied your code up a little bit, I believe the following will help you achieve your desired outcome:

```
 Sub SendEmail(what_address As String, carbon_copy As String, subject_line As String, mail_body_message As String)
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application: Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem: Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    olMail.To = what_address
    olMail.CC = carbon_copy
    olMail.Subject = subject_line
    olMail.Body = mail_body_message
    olMail.Send 'Send email
    'olMail.Display 'if you want to see the email before you decide to click send or not!
End Sub

Sub SendMassEmail()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim row_number As Long
Dim mail_body_message As String
row_number = 1
Last_Row_IN_Column_F = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
Do
    row_number = row_number + 1
    mail_body_message = ws.Range("U3").Text
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_name_here", ws.Range("E" & row_number))
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_email_here", ws.Range("F" & row_number))
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_supemail_here", ws.Range("H" & row_number))
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_date_here", ws.Range("B" & row_number))
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_compter_here", ws.Range("C" & row_number))
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_device_here", ws.Range("J" & row_number))
    'MsgBox mail_body_message
    Call SendEmail(ws.Range("F" & row_number).Text, ws.Range("H" & row_number).Text, "this is a test subject", mail_body_message)
Loop Until row_number = Last_Row_IN_Column_F

MsgBox "Emails Sent Completed", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried running it and i get a "ByRef argument mismatch" with the [mail_body_message] highlighted in the Call SendEmail row.

Comment: @mike000 just updated my answer, could you try once again? Remember that a String can only hold 255 characters, what I don't know is what the variable mail_body_message is holding... Or you could change the function call to ByVal, which won't coerce the variable to a specific data type.

Comment: the mail body message template itself is 241 words...

 I ran the new edit new error " user defined type not defined"  and now VBA highlights yellow Sub SendEmail(what_address As String, carbon_copy As String, subject_line As String, mail_body_message As String) and blue [olApp As Outlook.Application]

ugh lol

Comment: @Mike000 I believe you are trying to use Late Binding, could you try to go to: Tools > References > Check the checkbox in front of "Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library, then see if the issues persists?

Comment: That worked... email sent, but it didnt it tap into "U3".  The emails sent were blank in the main body.

Also i'd like to have a pop up when the macro is finished to notify completion

Comment: @Mike000 I've now updated my answer once more, I believe it should work now, I've tested it and it worked for me, please give it a try and let me know if any further issues. :)

Comment: *Just a hint:)* what about fully qualifying the worksheet reference by `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` *(if not contained in a personal macro library)* and code the `U3` assignment also via `ws`, i.e. 
`mail_body_message = ws.Range("U3").Text` ?

Comment: @T.M. Thanks for the hint, updated my answer to reflect your comment. :)